# Location where debug.log in Bit Builds

Tags: bit.dev

I'm wondering where I can find Debug.log when using Bit.dev on the Windows Platform.

I am getting an error while building and it's telling to at Debug.log for more details. Unfortunately, I can't find this file.

Comment: You may try `dir /s /b debug.log` in the root of your project / root of your system drive to recursively search for it, but usually Bit generates log files in the directory where the build command was executed

Comment: run `bit globals` to get information on location of various items. you can also add `--log` to any command, so Bit prints all information directly to the terminal.